# Updating records in hive tables

Tags: hive, hiveql, overwrite

How to overwrite certain records of a hive table?
eg:
I have a table t1 having 100 records. Now I have to overwrite only 30 of those 100 records.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports ACID properties from Hive-0.14. Using Hive transactions you can update or delete your existing records.

There are few rules to be followed for performing update and delete operations. You can refer [to this blog](https://acadgild.com/blog/transactions-in-hive/) on Hive transactions for more details and implementation.

Comment: basically,i have to merge two tables. If the two tables have matching IDs,the records in 1st table has to be overwritten by the records of the 2nd table.else the records of 2nd table will just be inserted into the 1st table.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is too low to directly answer to your comment, but here's a way to accomplish it:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_a
SELECT * FROM table_a a WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_b) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table_b;
```

Comment: Will the `NOT IN` behave the same way in this case as `NOT EXISTS`?  The [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries)  specifically says to use `NOT EXISTS`.